# MYSQL: Get next 'n' results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Right now I have a PHP script that is fetching the first three results from a MYSQL database using:

```
SELECT * FROM table Order by DATE DESC LIMIT 3;
```

After that command I wanted PHP to fetch the next three results, initially I was going to use:

```
SELECT * FROM table Order by DATE DESC LIMIT 3,3;
```

However there will be a delay between the two commands which means that it is very possible that a new row will be inserted into the table during the delay. My first thought was to store  the `DATE` value of the last result and then include a `WHERE DATE > $stored_date` but if entry 3 and 4 have the same date it will skip entry 4 and return results from 5 onward. This could be avoided using the primary key field which is an integer which increments automatically.

I am not sure which the best approach is, but I feel like there should be a more elegant and robust solution to this problem, however I am struggling to think of it.

---

Example table:

```
-------------------------------------------
| PrimaryKey | Data |         Date        |
-------------------------------------------
|      0     |  abc | 2014-06-17 11:43:00 |
|      1     |  def | 2014-06-17 12:43:00 |
|      2     |  ghi | 2014-06-17 13:43:00 |
|      3     |  jkl | 2014-06-17 13:56:00 |
|      4     |  mno | 2014-06-17 14:23:00 |
|      5     |  pqr | 2014-06-17 14:43:00 |
|      6     |  stu | 2014-06-17 15:43:00 |
-------------------------------------------
```

Where Data is the column that I want.

Comment: Post your table structure and some sample data.

Comment: What is it that the script is doing?

Comment: Why was this question marked down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best will be using primary key and select like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE pk < $stored_pk Order by DATE DESC LIMIT 3;
```

And if you have automatically generated PK you should use **ORDER BY pk** it will be faster

Comment: Thanks, Good point about the ordering not sure why I was sorting by date.

Answer (score 0):

Two options I can think of depending on what your script does:

You could either use transactions: performing these queries inside a transaction will give you a consistent view of the data.

Alternatively you could just use:

```
SELECT * FROM table Order by DATE DESC;
```

And only fetch the results as you need them.

Comment: The PHP script sends the data to another page where it is rendered as HTML and displayed to the user. When the user clicks next, the PHP gets the next 3 results and outputs them. Since multiple users will be using this at once having all of the results stored in the PHP is undesirable as the database is likely to get quite large.

Comment: Most database libraries don't pull every record straight into PHP. You need to request the next record (i.e. by calling `$mysqli->fetch_assoc()` or whatever is appropriate for the code you are using).